Diffie-hellman private key specification - necessity of most-significant bit in private key
In RFC7919 in regards to DH private keys, it states:

Traditional finite field Diffie-Hellman has each peer choose their secret exponent from the range [2, p-2]. Using exponentiation by squaring, this means each peer must do roughly 2×log2(p) multiplications, twice (once for the generator and once for the peer's public key). Peers concerned with performance may also prefer to choose their secret exponent from a smaller range, doing fewer multiplications, while retaining the same level of overall security. Each named group indicates its approximate security level and provides a lower bound on the range of secret exponents that should preserve it. For example, rather than doing 2×2×3072 multiplications for an ffdhe3072 handshake, each peer can choose to do 2×2×275 multiplications by choosing their secret exponent from the range [2274, 2275] (that is, an m-bit integer where m is at least 275) and still keep the same approximate security level.

In that example, a 275-bit key is used where the msb is set to 1. My question is, what's the point of having that constant 1 bit in the msb instead of just using a randomly generated 274-bit key directly? Are leading zeros less secure in DH private keys?


My question is, what's the point of having that constant 1 bit in the msb instead of just using a randomly generated 274-bit key directly?

It comes down to a concern about side channel attacks (specifically, one which depends on the time taken), and an attempt to try to make things constant time.
In some straight-forward approaches, the number of multiplications you do depends on the position of the most significant bit.  Now, if you picked an exponent from the range $(0, 2^{274}]$, the first couple of high order bits might happen to be 0; an implementor would then be tempted to skip the first few multiplications, which would make things faster, but might also indicate to someone listening in that the actual exponent is a bit smaller, which might allow him attack it a bit easier.
That said, the reality is a bit more complicated; for one, that rather assumes that you're doing the straight-forward modexp implementation (and not, say, the most obvious binary method - that has other leaks) - there are alternative methods that are always constant time even without fixing the msbit (of course, if the implementor knew about those, they likely wouldn't need the advice from the RFC).  IMHO, DKG should have suggested a modexp method for implementors who needed the advice (rather than just saying "make it constant time").
